# command line arguments PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code

```
import sys

def main()
    print(sys.argv)
```

Version - 3.3

File name Pytest.py

running the file with syntax pytest.py aaa bbb ccc

But it didn't print anything and not giving any error also

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never call `main()`.

Python has no special `main` function that is run automatically, so instead, you can place the code that you want to run when the file is called from the command line into a special `if` block:

```
import sys

def main():
    print(sys.argv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You (and the OP) forgot `:` for `main()`

Comment: The `__name__` convention is an important idiom, but for a simple test script, just don't put the code in a function. `import sys; print(sys.argv)`

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate @Blender's answer: Python functions does not compile like in C. Functions are *statements* - they are being executed when the control encounters them, and it begins at the first line of the file.

The following code is perfectly legal:

```
# get b somehow
if b:
    def foo(): return 1
else:
    def foo(): return 2

print(foo())
```